# Wordpress plugin: a safe way to store mySQL query contitions

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

lets say i want to create a wordpress plugin, which will get data from a plugins custom table in the wordpress database and add some content to each post. This woul propably look someting like this: 
`SELECT * FROM $my_table WHERE time BETWEEN $prevoius_post_time AND $current_post_time ORDER BY time LIMIT 5000`

There should be a way to modify this query by the posts editor to add some additional filters to this, so i would end up with something like:

`SELECT * FROM $my_table WHERE time BETWEEN $prevoius_post_time AND $current_post_time && $filter ORDER BY time LIMIT 5000`,

where `$filer` could be something like `filterrow1 != 300 && filterrow2 >=7`, which will be created using a form ($_POST) in the backend before publishing a new post.

Now i am not sure where to store the $filer variable, as i am a little bit afraid of SQL injections etc. Is it safe enough to store $filer in a posts meta `via update_post_meta()` and just receive it with the `get_post_meta()` function before the actual query?

Or am i missing any other and better way? 
Since the filters may get really complex, i dont really see any way of storing $filter as a array like $key => $value and generate the whole filter on each request.

Answer (score 0):

Hei.
You can use `$filter = mysql_real_escape_string($filter);` or you can use $wpdb prepare function (look up wordpress manual). It takes care of sql injections.